# How do you predict the behavior of GC

Tags: go

```golang
type BST struct {
    Root *Node
}

type Node struct {
    Key    int
    Parent *Node
    Left   *Node
    Right  *Node
}

func Init() *BST {
    var root Node
    var l Node

    root = Node{
        10,
        nil,
        &l,
        nil,
    }

    l = Node{
        5,
        &root,
        nil,
        nil,
    }

    t := BST{&root}
    return &t
}

func Init2() *BST {
    var root *Node
    var l *Node

    root = &Node{
        10,
        nil,
        l,
        nil,
    }

    l = &Node{
        5,
        root,
        nil,
        nil,
    }

    t := BST{root}
    return &t
}
```

I wrote 2 types of `Init()` to return a tree with 2 nodes. When I called `InorderPrint()` to the tree returned by `Init()`, the output was 5 10. When I called `InorderPrint()` to the tree returned by `Init2()`, the output was 10. I guess GC freed one of the nodes in the second case. I have no idea how to predict the behavior of GC.

Comment: "I guess GC freed one of the nodes in the second case." Your guess is wrong. GC never frees anything still in use. Your Init2 is just plain wrong, your root node contains a nil Left because `l` is nil when you construct `root`. Take the tour of Go for basic language fundamentals like this.

Comment: @Volker i didn't notice the zero value of a pointer is nil. this is not a problem with GC, thank you very much.

Comment: The GC is always 100% invisible to the operation of the program. If it's not, it's seriously broken. The only observable effect you'll see from the GC is occasional, microscopic pauses in the execution of your program, and memory usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get `Init2` to work the problem is here:

```golang
    l = &Node{
        5,
        root,
        nil,
        nil,
    }
```

In this line you are overwriting `l` and it will not change the value given to the `root` node.

Instead change the value underlying the pointer:

```golang
    *l = Node{
        5,
        root,
        nil,
        nil,
    }
```

For this to work you need to initialize `l` e.g. using new(Node):

```golang
l := new(Node)
```

Working sample with minimal changes: https://play.golang.org/p/idLimW79m5c

Comment: The problem of `Init2` is i assigned a new address to the pointer `l`. However, when the node root was constructed the address of `l` was the original one which is the zero value (nil) of a pointer in this case. Thank you for your answer.